# Javascript Callback reset Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, synchronous

Trying to reset an elements CSS transition property in a synchronous manner in order to allow an interactive drawer to slide close when the user removes their finger from the screen.

I've tested the function below with a callback placed inside and the transition property is resetting immediately after the function is called. How can I get this functions' contents to execute in order?

```
        $('.main-drawer-wrapper').on('touchend',function(){
        var newoffSet=$('.main-drawer-wrapper').offset().left;
        $('.main-drawer-wrapper').css('transition','margin-left 1s');
        if (newoffSet>halfSet){
            $('.main-drawer-wrapper').css('margin-left',0);
        }else{
            $('.main-drawer-wrapper').css('margin-left',offSet + 'px');     
        }
        (function(){
            $('.main-drawer-wrapper').css('transition','');
        })();
    })
```

Comment: You can have a look at [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end) article that shows you how to hook into transition end events

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `transitionend` event. Added a quick `setTimeout()` between adding the transition and margin, otherwise they fire at the same time and the transition may not happen.

```js
var $mainDrawerWrapper = $('.main-drawer-wrapper');

$mainDrawerWrapper.css('transition', 'margin-left 1s');
setTimeout(function() {
  $mainDrawerWrapper.css('margin-left', '100px').on('transitionend', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'transition': '',
      'margin-left': '0'
    });
  });
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-drawer-wrapper">main-drawer-wrapper</div>
```